# Given Y = g(X), why is Var(Y|X) = 0?

Tags: probability, variance

Given $Y = g(X)$, why is $Var(Y|X) = 0$?

After replacing $Y$ with $g(X)$...

$Var(g(X)|X) = 0$ is not intuitive to me. 
Intuitively, I feel like the $Var(g(X)|X)$ should be the whole function $g(X)$.

Any insights would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Roughly: Given. that you know $X$, $Y$ is constant, so has variance zero.

Comment: What level of answer are you looking for? Introductory probability? Measure-theoretic answer?

Comment: lol yikes I am incredibly dumb. Thank you for that answer, can't believe my thought process didn't even reach that

Comment: @3x89g2 also wondering if there is a more mathematical answer to that - such as using the law of conditional variance and such? Actually, I think you should be able to expand that out using the definition of variance and then work something out

Comment: For any (measurable) function $f(x)$, and any random variable $X$, we have $E[f(X)|X]=f(X)$.  I believe that if you define what you mean by conditional variance in terms of expectations, you can get the desired variance-0 result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}$This is easily done with the measure theoretic definition. One defines for a square integrable random variable $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\F$:
\begin{align}
\Var(X|\F):=\E[X^2|\F]-\E[X|\F]^2
\end{align}
Now we want $\Var(Y|X)=\Var(Y|\sigma (X))$, and that is:
\begin{align}
\Var(Y|\sigma(X))=\E[Y^2|\sigma(X)]-(\E[Y|\sigma(X)])^2
\end{align}
Since $Y=g(X)$ we have $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable (as long as $g$ is nice enough $(\star)$). That implies $\E[Y^2|\sigma(X)]=Y^2$ and $\E[Y|\sigma(X)]=Y$. Hence:
\begin{align}
\Var(Y|\sigma(X))=Y^2-Y^2=0
\end{align} 
$(\star)$: Surely one needs to require $g$ to be measurable and such that $\E[g(X)^2]$ exists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a definition for $E[Y \vert X]$.
\begin{align*}
Var (Y \vert X) &= E [ (Y - E[Y \vert X] )^2 \vert X] \\
&= E[Y^2 \vert X] - (E[Y \vert X])^2 \\
&= (g(X))^2 - (g(X))^2 \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}